# SSRS Page breaks works in designer, but doesn't work on the Server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a simple report, with 4 groups like here -

Group1

1st Child Group

2nd Child Group

Detail records

Group 1 Total

After each instance of Group 1, I need a break, so I naturally used this setting on the Group 1's properties - Page breaks -> "Between each instance of the group" and "Also at the end of a group".

This works perfectly on the designer, on my local instance of Visual studio 2008, but once I upload the report to the SSRS server (running SSRS 2008R2), the behavior of the page breaks is not working. First instance of the group1 gives the page break correctly, but the second and third instances doesn't. Any idea what I am missing ? Is there any setting on the server, that is messing up the page breaks on the report?

Note: I tried uploading the screenshots, but I don't have enough rep to do it.

Edit: @b3ko - I tried with IE8, Chrome & IE11

@kyzen - The behavior is, that the break appears before the totals of Group1. The 3rd item in the group 1 has no proper child rows on the report viewer. However if I export the results are proper , and as expected. but the report viewer doesnt render the report properly.

Edit 2 -

Finally solved the issue. I deleted the totals row for Group 1, then added the total by right clicking the "group 1" -> Add totals-> Below. That actually seems to create a lot of rows, but deleted unwanted rows, and kept the one row that was relevant. Finally that took care of the issue.

Comment: What browser are you using once deployed? I have seen that for chrome and ff sometimes look strange and do strange things. Try in IE (yuck)

Comment: @b3ko - you can actually fix (most of) that behavior with a few lines of javascript.  Dinesh - is your issue that you are seeing groups 2 & 3 on the same page, or is your issue that you're seeing empty pages between valid pages?

Comment: @b3ko / kyzen  Finally solved the issue. I deleted the totals row for Group 1, then added the total by right clicking the "group 1" -> Add totals-> Below. That actually seems to create a lot of rows, but deleted unwanted rows, and kept the one row that was relevant. Finally that took care of the issue.